# Sum of blank values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to make sum of blank values in SQL Server?

I tried with following but returns null

```
Declare @val varchar
Declare @columns varchar(20) 
declare @sql varchar(200)
set @columns= 'branch'

set @sql  = 'select ' + @val +'= sum(case when @columns = '''' then 1 else 0 end)
         from dbo.companies'
exec(@sql)
select @val
```

I need a dynamic SQL statement because values will be returned from stored procedure for each column.

Comment: I would suggest to use a print statement to get the actual statement that is being formed before you execute.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Of course it returns NULL. You define @val but don't assign it a value. Then you concatenate the strings together and since one is null the result is null. What about @columns? And why are you using dynamic sql in the first place? If you really do need dynamic sql (your explanation isn't clear) you should be using sp_executesql and parameters.

Comment: The more I read this the more I am convinced this is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Let us help you by explaining what you are really trying to do. We can help you find a better approach than dynamic sql to get results one column at a time.

Comment: This question just makes no sense.  The "sum of blank values" will be either `NULL` or `0` or generate an error (depending on how "blank" is represented).  I'm not sure why use of a stored procedure would mandate dynamic SQL on an existing table.  Sample data and desired results *might* help.

Comment: @SeanLange,
Sure, here is the sample data and expected results. I'm trying to achieve..

Sample Data:
Col1 Col2 Col3
ABC US 
ABC2  103
ABC3 US 103
ABC4  103
 US

Expected Results:
ColName Populated Blank_Null
Col1 4 1
Col2 3 2
Col3 3 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total stab in the dark, but I *think* what you're after is:

```
DECLARE @Count int, @Column sysname;
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @Column = N'SomeColumnName';

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @Count = COUNT(CASE ' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + N' WHEN '''' THEN 1 END) FROM dbo.companies;';
EXEC sp_excutesql @SQL, N'@Count int OUTPUT',@Count = @Count OUTPUT;
SELECT @Count;
```

*Edit: Note that that `''` and `NULL` are not the same value; something that you seem to be unaware of considering you where concatenating a variable (`@Val` of the datatype `varchar(1)`) with the value `NULL` to a literal string. `NULL + {expr} = NULL`. If you want to count rows with `NULL`, not a blank string is `IS NULL` (and you'll need to move the `WHEN`).*

Comment: this works well for me.. now how I use for case like when empty ('') and non empty records..
e.g.

Comment: The above **is** testing for a blank (`''`) @RuchitaP. `WHEN '''' THEN` equates to `WHEN '' THEN` outside of the dynamic SQL.

Comment: yes, how do we write case when not blank ('')
e.g.
SELECT  @Count = SUM(CASE [branch] WHEN = '' THEN 1 END)
     ,@actcount = SUM(CASE [branch] WHEN not '' THEN 1 END)
    FROM dbo.companies

Comment: I'm not here to support you @RuchitaP, you need to understand how to SQL works. You should know how to change a `CASE Value WHEN '' THEN...` to the opposite. That's all you need to do here. (Hint: Move the position of the `WHEN` and use `<>` or `!=`.)

Comment: sure, I agree and appreciate your help here.. I missed to post syntax I wrote in earlier comment.
I tried with
SET varSQL = N'SELECT  varCount = SUM(CASE ' + QUOTENAME(varColumn) + N' WHEN = '''' THEN 1 END)
     ,varactcount = SUM(CASE ' + QUOTENAME(varColumn) + N' WHEN <> '''' THEN 1 END)
    FROM dbo.companies';

Note: I'm writing var instead @ here (just for comment)..